# Converting a path to a string?

Tags: c#

I've got a button that saves the path to a folder as the text in a text box and I want to save it to the settings file in c# but I keep getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "System.windows.type.textbox" to String

Now the code I'm using to set the text box as the path is:

```
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
```

And the code I'm using to save it to the settings file is:

```
string pathh = textBox1;
Properties.Settings.Default.Path = textBox1;
```

Even if I replace

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Path = textBox1
Properties.Settings.Default.Path = pathh
```

I get the same error. Can some one tell me how to fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path is not the textbox but the TEXT of the textbox, so change

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Path = textBox1;
```

to

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Path = textBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Text` property of `TextBox` control class which is of `String` type like below. What you are trying is assigning a control instance to string and so receiving the error cause there are not same type.

```
string pathh = textBox1.Text;
```